# How to clone git repo from Windows to Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, git, tortoisegit

I previously kept a bare git repository on a Linux server and a working copy in my local Windows laptop for development (syncing to the server using TortoiseGit over ssh).  The server version was deleted/lost so I want to recreate the repo on the server using the latest commit from the local working copy on the Windows machine.

What is the best way to create this new remote bare repo copy on the remote Linux server from the Windows working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a bare repository on remote.

   I guess the answer provided by ad22 is good enough for you:

   ```
   mkdir -p myrepo.git
   cd myrepo.git
   git init --bare
   ```

   Otherwise, you need to find out how to create a bare repository on server.
2. Copy or Memo the URL of that just created bare repository.

   (Of cause, you need to have the right for accessing the URL.)
3. Add a new remote for your local repository.

   Since you already have a local repository,

   1. Right click in that repository, Click `TortoiseGit` -> `Settings`,
   2. Give the remote a shortname and URL you copied
   3. Add it and apply the setting.

   See:

   [image]
4. Push to remote by right clicking in local repository and click **Push** item.
5. In Push dialog,

   1. Select the remote you just added.
   2. Check the **Push all branches** checkbox if all branches can be public, otherwise you need push each branch one by one.
   3. Check the **Include Tags** checkbox if you want to push all tags.

   [image]

Suppose that's all. ^__^

Answer (score 5):

You can re-create the linux server repo using

```
mkdir -p myrepo.git
cd myrepo.git
git init --bare
```

On the local copy, assuming the remote URL is the same, do

```
git push origin <branch refspec>
```

for example

```
git push origin master
```

Note: If the remote URL has changed you can use

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you have many branches, `git push origin --all` followed by `git push origin --tags` is easier than pushing branches and tags one-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the repo on the server, then add the repo to your local one as remote if it is not the same location as before and push to it.

Answer (score 0):

On your Windows machine:

```
git clone --bare /path/to/local-working-copy-of-the-repo
```

The above command will create local-working-copy-of-the-repo.git folder.
Now copy the folder(bare repository) on to the Linux server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not the _best_ idea because creating a repo on Windows will create some settings in `.git/config` which are related to CR/LF and filesystem issues (their case [in]sensitivity, the lack of the 'x' flag). It's better to create an empty bare repo on Linux and then push to it.